# Deploying a Shiny app using a self-written package

Tags: r, shiny, package, cran, shinyapps

I have a working shiny app which uses library(coral),  where coral is a package I wrote myself, installed in the directory of the shiny app.

When I attempt to deploy my app onto shinyapps.io, I receive the following message:

```
Error: Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages:
- "coral"
Execution halted
```

From what I can gather online, the issue is probably that coral is not on CRAN,  so shinyapps.io cannot get the records for that package from there.

Is that a correct description of the problem? And is there a simple solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shinyapps.io can get packages from GitHub, if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shinyapps.io has the `devtools` package,
and it can install packages from GitHub,
if you don't mind putting your package there:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("youruser/yourpackage")
```

`devtools` has other functions too to install from other sources,
for example `install_bitbucket()` from bitbucket, `install_url()` from an arbitrary url and `install_file()` from a local file on disk.

To install from a local *directory*, you can use `install`:

```
devtools::install('path/to/r/package/dir')
```

Comment: Thanks janos - unfortunately I can't put the package in a public location; I don't suppose there is another way for devtools to install the coral package?

Comment: @JohnSmith something happened? Why did you unaccept?

Comment: Hi janos, sorry I can't seem to find the install_file function in devtools, and the install_local requires a tar, zip, tar.gz tar.bz2, tgz2 or tbz. If you know how to get around that, I'd be very grateful. I'm accepting anyway, sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnSmith I amended my answer again, you can install from a directory using `devtools::install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149643/discussion-between-john-smith-and-janos).