# R load an own package in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I made a package what I want use in a shiny app. On the computer it's working, but when I want to upload the app on shinyapps.io to share it, the uploading doesn't work... I tried to put the package in directory of the shiny app and to upload it too, but the same result results.

My problem is to upload the shiny app with my package.

When I upload my shinyapps with my package I get this :

```
devtools::install_github("zertupo/NxT")
library(NxT)
```

> Erreur : Unable to retrieve package records for the following
>   packages:
>   - "NxT" De plus : Warning message: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :   Failed to infer source for package 'NxT'; using latest available version on CRAN
>   instead

With only the devtools without the call to package :

```
devtools::install_github("zertupo/NxT")
```

I get this on shinyapps.io :

> An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for
>   clarification.

and the logs give me :

> Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
>   2018-05-15T14:49:06.583190+00:00 shinyapps[343120]: Warning: Error in next_word: could not find function "next_word"

It's well a package working on my computer with a DESCRIPTION file...And so without the call to package, it doesn't find the function...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying a Shiny app using a self-written package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197820/deploying-a-shiny-app-using-a-self-written-package)

Comment: yes, but it's not working... I posted a comment

Comment: Can you provide more information, for example error messages and a description of what actually happens when you try to load? Also, don't post questions or requests for clarification as answers on another thread. The information you posted there should be here in your question.

Comment: I edited, if you know something about this...