# deploy shiny app with package self written

Tags: r, github, shiny

First I know there is a question which looks like to mine here :
[Deploying a Shiny app using a self-written package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197820/deploying-a-shiny-app-using-a-self-written-package)

But there is not an answer at my question, so I ask again with my specificity.

I made a package what I want use in a shiny app. On the computer it's working, but when I want to upload the app on shinyapps.io to share it, the uploading doesn't work... I tried to put the package in directory of the shiny app and to upload it too, but the same result results.

My problem is to upload the shiny app with my package.

When I upload my shinyapps with my package I get this :

```
devtools::install_github("zertupo/NxT")
library(NxT)
```

> Erreur : Unable to retrieve package records for the following
>   packages:
>   - "NxT" De plus : Warning message: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :   Failed to infer source for package 'NxT'; using latest available version on CRAN
>   instead

With only the devtools without the call to package :

```
devtools::install_github("zertupo/NxT")
```

I get this on shinyapps.io :

> An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for
>   clarification.

and the logs give me :

> Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
>   2018-05-15T14:49:06.583190+00:00 shinyapps[343120]: Warning: Error in next_word: could not find function "next_word"

It's well a package, it works on my computer and he has a DESCRIPTION file...And so without the call to package, it doesn't find the function... I don't know how to proceed to make it work, I searched about the description file but it is in and it is good.

Comment: A brief visit to Github shows that it is not a valid R package there. I would expect to see a file with the extension `.Rproj`

Comment: OK I put the good directory, with the extension .Rproj, but the same result appears

Comment: It's still not a valid package because it has a folder NxT containing the files. These all need to be moved up a level.